# Split http traffic with CiliumNetworkPolicies

Tags: kubernetes-networkpolicy, cilium

With a number of k8s clusters, connected with cilium cluster mesh I am looking to split http traffic by verbs, with [L7 CiliumNetworkPolicies](https://github.com/cilium/cilium/blob/main/examples/policies/l7/http/l7_multi.yaml), so that (POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,HEAD) go to the master `Ceph Object Gateway` located in one k8s cluster and (GET) go to mirror `Ceph Object Gateway` located in another k8s cluster. [Multisite ceph object store](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/multisite/#diagram-replication-of-object-data-between-zones)

I am looking for my application to be able to write data into the distributed storage, so that the data gets replicated across connected ceph clusters. Then, once there is a need to read the data, the application will read it from the ceph cluster that is the closest.

Each `Ceph Object Gateway` - one per k8s cluster, has a service with identical name:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    io.cilium/global-service: "true"
  labels:
    app: rook-ceph-rgw
    rgw: m-harbor
  name: rook-ceph-rgw-m-harbor
  namespace: storage
spec:
  ports:
 - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: rook-ceph-rgw
  type: ClusterIP
```

They are `cilium global services` => `io.cilium/global-service: "true"`
In this particular case it would mean that:

1. Ceph Object Gateway(s) from the mirror cluster(s) would have to connect to `http://rook-ceph-rgw-m-harbor.storage.svc` on the master cluster. At the same time it has to talk to the `osd(s)` and `mon(s)` on the same cluster.

   - *How to ensure this using a (Cilium)NetworkPolicy*
2. The s3 client would need to write to the `http://rook-ceph-rgw-m-harbor.storage.svc` on the master cluster and read from the `http://rook-ceph-rgw-m-harbor.storage.svc` on the local cluster.

   - *How to ensure this using a (Cilium)NetworkPolicy*
3. *Should I go with [local-redirect-policy](https://docs.cilium.io/en/stable/network/kubernetes/local-redirect-policy/#local-redirect-policy) instead ?*

Mirror ceph-rgw(rhea cluster) pulls the zone from ceph-rgw(titan cluster)
[image: Mirror rgw pulls data from the master]

Client (Harbor registry) pulls an image from local ceph-rgw
[image: Client pulls an image from local ceph]